# Css doesn't pick the right stylesheet

Tags: html, css, mobile, media-queries

I've created a show/hide menu for a mobile screen size, but now I have problems with my css. I made different css stuff, so you can actually see changes when you make the site smaller. But since I made the show/hide menu, my code doesn't pick the right css stylesheets anymore. It only picks my media query at 32em, but I made one for 90, 78, 63, 49, 40 and 32 em. And every query except for 32 it doesn't pick. Why??

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Artikelpagina</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Test-artikelpagina.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="MediaQ.css" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script>(function(){document.documentElement.className='js'})();</script>
</head>
<body>

    <!-- header met logo & navigatie -->
    <header class="welkom">
        <h1>CMD Amsterdam - Intranet</h1>
        <p>Communication and Multimedia Design is een ontwerpopleiding voor interactieve media in Amsterdam.</p>
        <img src="cmd_logo.png" alt="cmd logo">

        <nav id="nav" role="navigation">
           <div class="show_menu_btn" data-target="#nav ul" data-shown-text="Sluit menu" data-hidden-text="Open menu">Open menu</div>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Opleiding</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Onderwijsprogramma</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Organisatie</a></li>
                <li><a href="Formulier.html">Stages en projecten</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Javascript

```
var show_menu = document.querySelector('.show_menu_btn');

show_menu.addEventListener('click', function() {
var target = document.querySelector(show_menu.getAttribute('data-target'));

if (target.style.display == "none") {
    target.style.display = "block";
    show_menu.innerHTML = show_menu.getAttribute('data-shown-text');

} else {
    target.style.display = "none";
    show_menu.innerHTML = show_menu.getAttribute('data-hidden-text');
}
});
```

CSS

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 90em) {

.show_menu_btn {
    display: none;
}

#nav ul {
    display: block;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: wheat;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
}

main>article>section>img {
    width: 80%;
    height: 40%;
    transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}

main>article>section>img:hover {
    transform: scale(1.5,1.5);
}

body>.welkom>#nav {
    display: block;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

body>.welkom>#nav>ul {
    background-color: transparent;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    float: none;
    font-size: 1em;
    padding-left: 0em;
}

body>.welkom>#nav>ul>li {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 0.1em;
    position: relative;
    float: inherit;
    padding: 0.25em 1em;
    padding-bottom: 0.5em;
    margin: 0em 2em 1em 0em;
    text-align: center;
    width: 90%;
}

main>article>section>video {
    width: 100%;
}

main>article>header>picture>img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
}
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------*/
@media only screen and (max-width:78em) {
body {
    width:96%;
}

main {
    width: 71%;
}

footer {
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 1em;
}

#sitemap {
    margin-right: 1em;
    order: 1;
    width: 30%;
    margin-left: 0em;
}

#contact {
    margin-right: 1em;
    width: 30%;
    order: 3;
    margin-left: 0em;
}

#search {
    margin-right: 1em;
    order: 4;
    margin-left: 0em;
}

#about {
    margin-right: 1em;
    width: 30%;
    order: 2;
    margin-left: 0em;
}

#credits {
    order: 5;
}
}

/*-------------------------------------------------------------------*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 63em) {

.no-js .show_menu_btn {
    display: none;
}

.no-js #nav ul {
        display: block;
}

body {
    background-color: wheat;
    width: 96%;
    margin-left: 0.2em;
    margin-right: 0.2em;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
}

body>.welkom {
    display: inline-block;
    flex-direction: row;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    background-color: #FFC844;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
body>.welkom>#nav {
    overflow: hidden;
}

body>.welkom>#nav>ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
    font-size: 1em;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    padding: 0.2em;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
}

body>.welkom>nav>ul>li:first-of-type {
    padding: 0em;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 0em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    margin: 0 .8em .8em 0;
    width: 10%;
}

body>.welkom>#nav>ul>li:nth-of-type(2) {
    padding: 0em;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 0em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    margin: 0 .8em .8em 0;
    width: 10%;
}

body>.welkom>#nav>ul>li:nth-of-type(3) {
    padding: 0em;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 0em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    margin: 0 .8em .8em 0;
    width: 25%;
}

body>.welkom>#nav>ul>li:nth-of-type(4) {
    padding: 0em;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 0em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    margin: 0 .8em .8em 0;
    width: 15%;
}

body>.welkom>#nav>ul>li:nth-of-type(5) {
    padding: 0em;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 0em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    margin: 0 .8em .8em 0;
    width: 20%;
}


main>article>section>img {
    width: 35%;
    height: 35%;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 1em;
}

main {
    display: inline-block;
    flex-direction: row;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

main>article>header {
    float: none;
}

main>article>header>picture>img {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    float: left;
    padding: 1em;
    padding-top: 0em;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
    padding-left: 0em;
}

main>article>section>video {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.related {
    display: inline-block;
    flex-direction: row;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    position: relative;
    width: 45%;
}

.related>article>section>ul>li {
    font-size: 0.7em;
}

article>section>ul>li a {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

main>form {
    width: 100%;
}

main>fieldset {
    padding-right: 0em;
    width: 100%;
}

aside {
    display: inline-block;
    flex-direction: row;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    position: relative;
    width: 45%;
}

footer {
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 1em;
}

#sitemap {
    margin-right: 1em;
    order: 1;
    width: 30%;
    margin-left: 0em;
}

#contact {
    margin-right: 1em;
    width: 30%;
    order: 3;
    margin-left: 0em;
}

#search {
    margin-right: 1em;
    order: 4;
    margin-left: 0em;
}

#about {
    margin-right: 1em;
    width: 30%;
    order: 2;
    margin-left: 0em;
}

#credits {
    order: 5;
}

fieldset {
    width: 40%;
}
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------------*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 49em) {

.no-js .show_menu_btn {
    display: none;
}

.no-js #nav ul {
        display: block;
}

body {
    width: 95%;
    background-color: green;
}

body>.welkom>#nav>ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
    font-size: 1em;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
}

body>.welkom>#nav>ul>li:first-of-type {
    padding: 0em;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 0em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    margin: 0 .8em .8em 0;
    width: 10%;
}

body>.welkom>#nav>ul>li:nth-of-type(2) {
    padding: 0em;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 0em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    margin: 0 .8em .8em 0;
    width: 10%;
}

body>.welkom>#nav>ul>li:nth-of-type(3) {
    padding: 0em;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 0em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    margin: 0 .8em .8em 0;
    width: 25%;
}

body>.welkom>#nav>ul>li:nth-of-type(4) {
    padding: 0em;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 0em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    margin: 0 .8em .8em 0;
    width: 15%;
}

body>.welkom>#nav>ul>li:nth-of-type(5) {
    padding: 0em;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 0em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    margin: 0 .8em .8em 0;
    width: 20%;
}

body>.welkom>#nav>ul>li {
    font-size: 0.9em;
}

main {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1em;
}

main>article>header>picture>img {
    display: none;
}

main>article>section>video {
    width: 100%;
}

main>article>section>img {
    width: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

.related {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1em;
    float: none;
}

.related>article>section>ul>li:first-of-type + li {
font-size: 0.8em;
}

.mededelingen {
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    background-color: #FFC844;
    position: relative;
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding-right: 1em;
}

aside {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
    padding: 1em;
}

.uitagenda {
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    background-color: #FFC844;
    position: relative;
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding-right: 1em;
}

footer {
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 1em;
}

#sitemap {
    margin-right: 1em;
    order: 1;
    width: 30%;
    margin-left: 0em;
}

#contact {
    margin-right: 1em;
    width: 30%;
    order: 3;
    margin-left: 0em;
}

#search {
    margin-right: 1em;
    order: 4;
    margin-left: 0em;
}

#about {
    margin-right: 1em;
    width: 30%;
    order: 2;
    margin-left: 0em;
}

#credits {
    order: 5;
}

#feedback {
    align-self: flex-end;
}
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------------*/
@media screen and ( min-width: 40em ) {

.no-js .show_menu_btn {
    display: none;
}

.no-js #nav ul {
        display: block;
}

body {
    width: 93%;
    background-color: lavenderblush;
}

 body>.welkom>#nav>ul>li:first-of-type {
    padding: 0em;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 0em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    margin: 0 .8em .8em 0;
    width: 10%;
    margin-right: 0em;
}

body>.welkom>#nav>ul>li:nth-of-type(2) {
    padding: 0em;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 0em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    margin: 0 .8em .8em 0;
    width: 15%;
    margin-right: 0em;
}

body>.welkom>#nav>ul>li:nth-of-type(3) {
    padding: 0em;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 0em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    margin: 0 .8em .8em 0;
    width: 26%;
    margin-right: 0em;
}

body>.welkom>#nav>ul>li:nth-of-type(4) {
    padding: 0em;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 0em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    margin: 0 .8em .8em 0;
    width: 15%;
}

body>.welkom>#nav>ul>li:nth-of-type(5) {
    padding: 0em;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 0em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    margin: 0 .8em .8em 0;
    width: 20%;
}

body>.welkom {
    display: inline-block;
    flex-direction: row;
    vertical-align: top;
    order: 1;
    padding: 1em;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0em;
}

body>.welkom>#nav {
    display: block;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

body>.welkom>img {
    display: none;
}

.welkom>p {
    margin-top: 0em;
}

main {
    flex-direction: column;
    order: 2;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 1em;
    padding: 1em;
}
main>article>section>video {
    width: 100%;
}

main>article>section>img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 0.5em;
}

label {
    width: 100%;
}

fieldset {
    width: 90%;
}

aside {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    order: 2;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 1em;
    padding: 1em;
    float: none;
}

.related {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    order: 2;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
    margin-top: 1em;
    padding: 1em;
}

article>section>ul>li a {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1.3em;
}

footer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    order: 2;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0em;
}

#sitemap {
    order: 1;
    margin-right: 0em;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-left: 1em;
    width: 100%;
}

#contact {
    order: 3;
    margin-right: 0em;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
}

#search {
    order: 4;
    margin-right: 0em;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#about {
    order: 2;
    margin-right: 0em;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 0.5em;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#credits {
    order: 5;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#feedback {
    order: 6;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#about {
    margin-right: 1em;
    padding-left: 0.5em;
}

}
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 32em) {

.no-js .show_menu_btn {
    display: none;
}

.no-js #nav ul {
        display: block;
}

.js .show_menu_btn {
    display: block;
}

.js #nav ul { display: none; }
}

.show_menu_btn {
    width: 75%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0.3em;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    background: #88b47f;
}

#nav ul {
    display: block;
}

#nav ul li {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #6f6f7a;
}

#nav ul li:hover {
    background: #88b47f;
}

#nav ul a {
    display: block;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #eee;
    border-bottom: none;
}


body {
    width: 90%;
    margin-right: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: wheat;
}

body>.welkom {
    display: inline-block;
    flex-direction: row;
    vertical-align: top;
    order: 1;
    padding: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.welkom {
    background-image: url(Banner.jpg);
}

body>.welkom {
    margin-top: 0em;
    margin-bottom: 0em;
}

body>.welkom>#nav {
    display: block;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

body>.welkom>#nav>ul {
    background-color: transparent;
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    float: none;
    font-size: 1em;
}

body>.welkom>#nav>ul>li:first-of-type {
    padding: 0em;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 0em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    margin: 0 .8em .8em 0;
    width: 100%;
}

body>.welkom>#nav>ul>li:nth-of-type(2) {
    padding: 0em;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 0em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    margin: 0 .8em .8em 0;
    width: 100%;
}

body>.welkom>#nav>ul>li:nth-of-type(3) {
    padding: 0em;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 0em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    margin: 0 .8em .8em 0;
    width: 100%;
}

body>.welkom>#nav>ul>li:nth-of-type(4) {
    padding: 0em;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 0em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    margin: 0 .8em .8em 0;
    width: 100%;
}

body>.welkom>#nav>ul>li:nth-of-type(5) {
    padding: 0em;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 0em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    margin: 0 .8em .8em 0;
    width: 100%;
}
body>.welkom>img {
    display: none;
}

.welkom>p:first-of-type {
    color: white;
}

.welkom>p {
    margin-top: 0em;
}

main {
    flex-direction: column;
    order: 2;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 1em;
    padding: 1em;
}

main>article>section>video {
    width: 100%;
}

main>article>section>img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 0.5em;
}

label {
    width: 100%;
}

fieldset {
    width: 90%;
}

aside {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    order: 2;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 1em;
    padding: 1em;
    float: none;
}

.related {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    order: 2;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
    margin-top: 1em;
    padding: 1em;
}

article>section>ul>li a {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1.3em;
}

footer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    order: 2;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0em;
}

#sitemap {
    order: 1;
    margin-right: 0em;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-left: 1em;
    width: 100%;
}

#contact {
    order: 3;
    margin-right: 0em;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
}

#search {
    order: 4;
    margin-right: 0em;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#about {
    order: 2;
    margin-right: 0em;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 0.5em;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#credits {
    order: 5;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#feedback {
    order: 6;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#about {
    margin-right: 1em;
    padding-left: 0.5em;
}
}
```

Comment: See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra closing bracket in this section

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 32em) {
  .no-js .show_menu_btn {
      display: none;
  }
  .no-js #nav ul {
      display: block;
  }
  .js .show_menu_btn {
      display: block;
  }
  .js #nav ul {
    display: none;
  }
} /* this right here, take it out */ 
... /* more code here */
} /* closing bracket */
```

So the rest of the styles after that bracket are outside of the media query and get applied no matter what

```js
var show_menu = document.querySelector('.show_menu_btn');

show_menu.addEventListener('click', function () {
    var target = document.querySelector(show_menu.getAttribute('data-target'));

    if (target.style.display == "none") {
        target.style.display = "block";
        show_menu.innerHTML = show_menu.getAttribute('data-shown-text');

    } else {
        target.style.display = "none";
        show_menu.innerHTML = show_menu.getAttribute('data-hidden-text');
    }
});
```

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 90em) {
   body {
     background: red;       
   }
}
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------*/
 @media only screen and (max-width:78em) {
    body {
        width:96%;
        background-color: blue;
    }
}
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------*/
 @media only screen and (max-width: 63em) {
    body {
        background-color: yellow;
    }
}
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------*/
 @media only screen and (max-width: 49em) {
    body {
        width: 95%;
        background-color: green;
    }
}
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------*/
 @media screen and (max-width: 40em) {
    body {
        width: 93%;
        background-color: lavenderblush;
    }
}
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------*/
 @media only screen and (max-width: 32em) {
    body {
        width: 90%;
        background-color: gray;
    }
}
```

```html
<header class="welkom">
     <h1>CMD Amsterdam - Intranet</h1>

    <p>Communication and Multimedia Design is een ontwerpopleiding voor interactieve media in Amsterdam.</p>
    <img src="cmd_logo.png" alt="cmd logo">
    <nav id="nav" role="navigation">
        <div class="show_menu_btn" data-target="#nav ul" data-shown-text="Sluit menu" data-hidden-text="Open menu">Open menu</div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Opleiding</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Onderwijsprogramma</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Organisatie</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="Formulier.html">Stages en projecten</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

UPDATE: `min-width: 40em` should be `max-width: 40em`

Comment: Hmm, I took it out, but it doesn't change anything.. But thanks for your feedback!

Comment: I added a code snippet. Do you see the changes happening there?

Comment: Yeah, I see it! But, the only change you made was taking out the last curly bracket? Because, it doesn't work at mine

Comment: It's not the last `}` in the media query, its the one at after `.js #nav ul { }`

Comment: It worked! But as you can see, it doesn't pick all my media queries. Because when I load the code snippet in full screen, it starts with screen size 40 em, then goes to 63 em and finally 32 em. But I have way more, so do you maybe know why it doesn't run logically through my media queries?

Comment: Ah, I found the problem. You have `min-width: 40em` when the rest are `max-width`

Comment: Thank you so much!! So stupid I didn't see that tiny mistake, I'm so sorry for that.

Comment: No worries, it happens to all of us. I'm glad to help :)